# Python 3 SublimeText 3 with open() resulting in FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to read this .txt file through Python (3.6.5), using SublimeText3 (3.1.1).  learning_python.txt is in the same directory as my python program.  I tried to make it an absolute filepath but getting FileNotFoundError either way.  I also tried running it through Terminal with the same outcome.  Is the code wrong?

```
filename = 'learning_python.txt'

print("--- Reading in the entire file:")
with open(filename) as f:
contents = f.read()
print(contents)
```

Traceback is:

```
--- Reading in the entire file:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sulli\Documents\Coding\Python Crash Course\Ch_10_Files_Exceptions\about_python.py", line 6, in <module>
with open(filename) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/sulli/Documents/Coding/Python Crash Course/Ch_10_Files_Exceptions/learning_python.txt'
```

Comment: At the top of your script put in `import os`, followed by `print(os.getcwd())`. What is the path it outputs, and are you positive that `learning_python.txt` is in the said directory?

Comment: Which direction do you think the slashes in the filename ought to go? I dunno if it matters in Python, or if Windows 10 is smart enough to figure that out on its own yet or not.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue here was I had named learning_python.txt file with the .txt at the end just like it is in the code.  When I deleted the .txt on the text file itself, it worked in Python to find learning_python.txt.  Python must have seen it as learning_python.txt.txt.

Comment: it seems to me that in your windows configuration you have not enabled the visibility of the extensions, and instead of having the file somefile.txt you have a file called somefile.txt.txt